# what is request._cookies in django?

Tags: python, django, django-views

I find  `cookies['cpu'] = request._cookies['cpu']`  in a `view.py` of an app, I do not know what the `request._cookies['cpu']` is and can't find it in google or the django documentation.

Comment: Means the app is using a cookie by name 'cpu'. The _cookie is like a private variable of the request object.

Answer (score 1):

A [HTTP Cookie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie) is data that is initially sent from the website and stored on a user's browser. This data is persistently stored, you can take a look at your cookies right now:

[image]

[image]

As you can see, stackoverflow stores these cookies, and when you send a request to the server, you can the request can include data from the cookies. The `_cookies` accesses these cookies.

You couldn't find it in the docs because it doesn't exist, the original creator of the script might have chosen to add a separate attribute, this is unclear since we cannot see the views.py file itself. The only attribute for a `HTTPRequest` that is relevant to what you're asking is `HTTPRequest.COOKIES`, which is a python dictionary of values.

Comment: the 69,74,79 line of https://github.com/retspen/webvirtmgr/blob/master/instance/views.py

Comment: I want to know why there is a '_' begin cookies.

Comment: @tft It looks like this uses ModPython, which modifies the original HTTPRequest object https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/googleappengine/python/+/b7630182d8b3dc583ad2116053d69fdc59c324a6/lib/django_1_4/django/core/handlers/modpython.py